# build.gradle.kts syntax sugar - explanation

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I was searching in the Internet but I have not found answer for my question regarding to build.gradle.kts syntax.

I haven't found any syntax regarding to below ***application*** plugin adding:

```
plugins {

// Apply the Kotlin JVM plugin to add support for Kotlin on the JVM.
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version("1.3.21")

// Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
application

//id("kotlin-android")
```

I mean, what kind of syntax stay behind ***application***?
It only looks like a class member name. Maybe is it a function call? but it has no brackets.
I don't catch this kotlin syntax sugar.

Additional, I have not found plugins (and others blocks) implementation in gradle repository. Someone know where it is located? I am just curious how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the implementation of `application` it should  bring you to the source:

```
/**
 * The builtin Gradle plugin implemented by [org.gradle.api.plugins.ApplicationPlugin].
 *
 * Visit the [plugin user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) for additional information.
 *
 * @see org.gradle.api.plugins.ApplicationPlugin
 */
inline val org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.`application`: org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependencySpec
    get() = id("org.gradle.application")
```

So `application` is just an extension function on `PluginDependenciesSpec` or `plugins { }`